# Stop regex at first instance (awk)

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have lines of the form

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXwordYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY<R>ZZZZZ
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[[YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY<R>ZZZZZ
```

I don't want to get into the syntax issues, but what I want to do with any line that contains `<R>` is replace it with the following text

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{wordYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZ}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{[[YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZ}
```

Getting rid of the `<R>` is trivial:

```
str = $0
sub(/<R>/, "", str)
print str
```

Assume that the string is created by a program that I have no control over, and the transformed representation is processed by yet another program, and I have somehow (by magic) transform the output of program A into suitable syntax for program B, e.g.

```
A ... | awk ... | B ...
```

Somewhere between the **sub** and the **print**, I want to surround the data with **{}** as indicated.  The sequence of **XXX...XXX**, **YYY...YY** and **ZZ...ZZ** are arbitrary character sequences of arbitrary length, so I want to split the string at the word "**word**" or at the first **[**, and retain those characters in the result string.  Nothing I have found seems to quite answer this question. The closing **}** always goes at the end of the line, so that's equally trivial to deal with.

Note: This is a simplified description of a far more complicated syntax, but describing the details of the syntax would not be productive.

Comment: This intro about `<R>` was a bit disorienting. You just want to put into `{}` a last (and well defined) part of the string, right? And just code it together with deleting `<R>`. Is your sample input one or two lines?

Answer (score 1):

With a sed that has a `-E` arg to support EREs, e.g. GNU or OSX/BSD sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/((word|\[\[).*)<R>(.*)/{\1\3}/' file
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{wordYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZ}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{[[YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZ}
```

With a POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(\(word\|\[\[\).*\)<R>\(.*\)/{\1\3}/' file
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{wordYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZ}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{[[YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZ}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to surround the last part of the line (starting with `word` or `[`) with `{}`, you could use the `GNU awk` string function [`gensub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

> gensub() provides an additional feature that is not available in sub()
> or gsub(): the ability to specify components of a regexp in the
> replacement text.

```
awk '{ print gensub(/([word|\[].+)$/, "{&}", "g", $0) }' file
```

Putting it together with your existing code for deleting `<R>`:

```
awk '{
    str = $0
    sub(/<R>/, "", str)
    print gensub(/([word|\[].+)$/, "{&}", "g", str)
}' file
```

output:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{wordYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZ}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{[[YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZ}
```

Note: I have assumed that your sample input is two lines, so regex matches until end of line (`$`). If it is one line, you just have to modify the end of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk` with alternation regex:

```
awk '{sub(/word|\[\[/, "{&"); sub(/<R>/, ""); sub(/$/, "}")} 1' file
```

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{wordYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZ}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{[[YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZ}
```

This `sed` should also work for you:

```
sed -E 's/word|\[\[/{&/; s/<R>//; s/$/}/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^(.*)(word.*)<R>(.*) \1(\[.*)<R>\3$/\1{\2\3}\n\1{\4\3}/' file
```

Pattern match on a line and substitute using back references and groupings if a match is successful.

N.B. The back references `\1` and `\3` are used in the LHS of the regexp.

---

The use of `Y`'s in the question are inconsistent i.e. different length.